# How do I determine height and scrolling position of window in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab the height of the window and the scrolling offset in jQuery, but I haven't had any luck finding this in the jQuery docs or Google.

I'm 90% certain there's a way to access height and scrollTop for an element (presumably including the window), but I just can't find the specific reference.

Comment: How about without jQuery?

Comment: @Costa That has likely been asked elsewhere on StackOverflow, and if not it deserves to be its own question.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

From jQuery Docs:

```
const height = $(window).height();
const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Figures I just missed it in the docs; searched them, but their organization frankly makes no sense to me (still thinking in Mootools, I suppose).  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work in any browser for jQuery 1.3.2 even though it was supposedly added in an earlier version. Either that or I have something wrong with my code here

Comment: $(window).height() gives the height viewport and not the scroll height. $(document).height() gives the real scroll height, as Aidamina suggested.

Comment: I'm often amazed at how many upvotes simple things like this attract, but since I've looked this up twice this week already, have another +1

Answer (score 41):

from http://api.jquery.com/height/ (Note: The difference between the use for the window and the document object)

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

from http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
$(window).scrollTop() // return the number of pixels scrolled vertically
```

Answer (score 12):

Pure JS

```
window.innerHeight
window.scrollY
```

is more than 10x faster than jquery (and code has similar size):

[image]

Here you can perform test on your machine: https://jsperf.com/window-height-width

Comment: `window.scrollY`, get scroll top height

Answer (score 6):

```
$(window).height()

$(window).width()
```

There is also a plugin to jquery to determine element location and offsets

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions

scrolling offset = offsetHeight property of an element

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. It's not exactly what I was looking for as I was trying to avoid using another plugin, but you got me searching in the right direction. In the end, it turns out what I really needed was '$(window).scrollTop()' to figure out how much of the page has scrolled past the viewport to adjust elements accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scroll to a point of an element. You can use Jquery function to scroll it up/down.

```
$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
            }, 'slow');
```