# How to check if webpage page is scrolled?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll, mouse-position

Is there any way in javascript to check if web page has been vertically scrolled?
specially for Internet Explorer? I need to get the mouse position in IE but using
jQuery event e.pageY it gives correct value when page is not scrolled but when page is scrolled down then it gives wrong position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this question if you are comfortable with using jQuery:

[How do I determine height and scrolling position of window in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303767/how-do-i-determine-height-and-scrolling-position-of-window-in-jquery)

Comment: thanks a lot. my problem is solved. i just need $(window).scrollTop.

Comment: Jquery might not be the first choice anymore. I strongly recommend looking into the IntersectionObserver which by now is even a native browser feature. Besides becoming the new standard it also is better from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 48):

```
if (!$(window).scrollTop()) { // abuse 0 == false :)
  alert("You are at the top of this window");
}
```

Comment: Or without jQuery `if(window.pageYOffset == 0) {alert("Top of the window");}`