# Scroll up and Down Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am new to jQuery and I need to make my bootstrap navbar on scroll down have a background color and on scroll top be transparent.

I Know how to use the `.scroll`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).scroll(function(){
         $(".navbar").css("background-color","#e74c3c"); 
      });
      });
```

But I need to use scroll up and down option , please help. Thanks !

Comment: Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074802/how-to-check-if-webpage-page-is-scrolled