# load more content from an array using codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I am using CodeIgniter. In my controller I am decoding a JSON response and simply displaying the values upon loading a view. I am simply displaying all my content from a JSON array (**no database used**). It is completely an array from which i am rendering the data.I want to autoload the content whilst scrolling.

**Example:**

```
 $resultjson = $this->curl->simple_get("http://www.test.com/api/records.php?ak=XXXXXXXX&ts=XXXXXXXX&sig=XXXXXXXX&postano=XXXXXX&count=100");
```

How can I fetch 10 records when autoloaded? Just like the http://pinterest.com/ mechanism. How can I achieve this?

Are there any plugins? Does CodeIgniter already have a solution for it such that I can use classes or libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/), [scrollTop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303767/how-do-i-determine-height-and-scrolling-position-of-window-in-jquery) and the $.ajax();

Basicly catch the scroll event, see if `$(window).scrollTop()` is higher than `<div id="auto_load"></div>` (through [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)) and run ajax once if that's the case.

`div#auto_load` would be places bellow loaded content, and will "jump" down once content is added.

Example:

```
var ajax_once = false;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if (ajax_once)
        return;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('div#auto_load').offset().top) {
        ajax_once = true;
        $.ajax({
            /* Url, dataType json etc. */
        }).done(function(data) {
            /* use the data */
            ajax_once = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Robin. But can you please tell me where should the ajax places. Either in view or in controller class. I never used ajax concepts before.. I hope this should be included in controller am i right? the url i am decoding will have count value &count=20

Comment: $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
alert('one');
    if (ajax_once)
        return;
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('div#auto_load').offset().top()) {
           alert('two');
        ajax_once = true;
        $.ajax({
            /* Url, dataType json etc. */
        }).done(function(data) {
            /* use the data */
            ajax_once = false;
        }); This condition always fails y? alert "one prints but "two doesn't"!

Comment: do you have mentioned `<div id="auto_load"></div` element, and does nothing `alert()`?

Comment: Yes i mentioned auto_load div. but it doesn't print alert named two

Comment: Then troubleshot `$(this).scrollTop()` and `$('div#auto_load').offset().top()` till you know what's up.

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter is a php framework which means server side therefore no client side logic built in.

You can use a jQuery plugin for that called infinite scroll. Here is the link to it: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: Actually i gone through this http://www.quora.com/CodeIgniter/How-to-auto-load-the-page-when-scrolling. But i dont think this plugin really works fine. The documentation is not clear. Let me try again

Comment: Interesting typo in the name of the framework... `GodeIgniter` alsmot like `GodIgniter`. :)