# Making a sidebar menu fade in then fade back out

Tags: jquery, fadein, jquery-waypoints

I am working with a one page site that is relying on [jQuery Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints) to reveal the side navigation once the user scrolls down a bit.

I currently have the menu appearing correctly but I need the menu to hide again once the user scrolls back up to the top, since there will be a main navigation located at the top of the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="side-nav" style="opacity: 0; ">
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a class="last" href="#stay">Stay</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#side-nav').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#side-nav').waypoint(function () {
        $('#side-nav').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 'slow');
    }, {

    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GK6Mf/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't just post a link to an external site. Post relevant code and what you are having issues with

Answer (score 0):

Using this other Post you can learn how to determine what position the scroll bar is in. From there you can hide/show your side navigation when it is in the area you want it to be.

[How do I determine height and scrolling position of window in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303767/how-do-i-determine-height-and-scrolling-position-of-window-in-jquery)

Comment: I am a newer jQuery user. Would you mind going into more detail of how this would be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `direction` parameter passed to the callback in Waypoints, and fade to the right opacity depending on whether the value of that parameter is "down" or "up":

```
$('#side-nav').css('opacity', 0);
$('#side-nav').waypoint(function (direction) {
    $('#side-nav').animate({
        opacity: direction === 'down' ? 1 : 0
    }, 'slow');
});
```